# PowerShell multiplier not recognized using Read-Host

Tags: powershell, read-host

Is there a way to get Read-Host to recognize PowerShell multipliers like KB, MB,GB,TB, and PB? The first example works just fine if I populate the $freespace variable by hand but does not work in the second example using Read-Host to populate the $freespace variable. The has to be a simple solution to get prompt for user input and have the value recognized as an integer rather than a string.

```
#this works just fine. The PowerShell multiplier GB is recognized if typed in.

$freespace = 6GB

If ($freeSpace -le 5GB) {
    Write-Host “Free disk space is less than 5 GB”
} ElseIf ($freeSpace -le 10GB) {
    Write-Host “Free disk space is less than 10 GB”
} ElseIf ($freeSpace -le 20GB) {
    Write-Host “Free disk space is less than 20 GB”
} Else {
    Write-Host “Free disk space is more than 20 GB”
}

#This does not work. The variable is populated by Read-Host as a [string] 

$freespace = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter a value for Freespace'

If ($freeSpace -le 5GB) {
    Write-Host “Free disk space is less than 5 GB”
} ElseIf ($freeSpace -le 10GB) {
    Write-Host “Free disk space is less than 10 GB”
} ElseIf ($freeSpace -le 20GB) {
    Write-Host “Free disk space is less than 20 GB”
} Else {
    Write-Host “Free disk space is more than 20 GB”
}
```

Comment: `$freespace = Invoke-Expression $freespace`. Using *iex* here as I'm not sure the *invocation operator* would work (`&`) in this scenario (*not at my desk to test*). You're passing it a string and it will be read *as is*. You have to allow the expression to be executed.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala - That would work but it would also execute `remove-item c:\* -rec -force -ea continue`. Depending on how the script is presented to users, this could be security risk.

Comment: @Lieven, not sure how you could enter an entire cmdlet based off a prompt that reads *"Please enter a value for Freespace"*. Would be no different than just saying it would be dangerous to execute `Remove-Item c:\ -Recurse` in the shell itself... but, I see your point. We can work around it by parsing the data and evaluating what was passed to the variable. What would you recommend?

Comment: The usual workaround is to cast to a numeric value. A safe way to do that is to use the `-as` operator (see my answer).

Comment: @AbrahamZinala - I should have focused more on the *depending how the script is presented to users* . If the script is running with alternate credentials, it could allow a user to execute commands he otherwise would not have the rights to.

Comment: The answer you accepted may contain the best solution for your particular use case, but it doesn't match _what you asked_, which is, "Is there a way to get Read-Host to recognize PowerShell multipliers like KB, MB,GB,TB, and PB?" For the benefit of future readers it is better to accept answers based on whether they address the question _as asked_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correction

```
$freeSpace = $null
do {
 [int]$freeSpaceRaw = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter a value for Freespace in GB example 5 for 5GB '
  try { $freeSpace = 0 + $freeSpaceRaw } catch { Write-Warning 'Please enter a valid number.' }
} while ($null -eq $freeSpace)

If ($freeSpace -lt 5) {
    "Free disk space is less than 5 GB"
} ElseIf ($freeSpace -lt 10) {
    "Free disk space is less than 10 GB"
} ElseIf ($freeSpace -lt 20) {
    "Free disk space is less than 20 GB"
} Else {
    "Free disk space is more than 20 GB"
}
```

Comment: Remove the `[int]` cast, or you'll get an error that in effect exits the loop if the users enters a value that can't be interpreted as a string. On a meta note: to improve your answers after posting them, _edit_ them - don't post the update _as another answer_. Please delete your original answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
$freespace = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter a value for Freespace'
```

The value stored in the `$freespace` variable will be of type `[String]`, whereas you probably want `[UInt64]` (positive integer). You can convert the `[String]` type to the `[UInt64]` type using code like the following:

```
do {
  $entry = Read-Host "Please enter a value for freespace, in GB"
  $freespace = $entry -as [UInt64]
  $ok = ($null -ne $freespace) -and ($freespace -lt 1024)
  if ( -not $ok ) {
    Write-Host "Please enter a value in the range 0 to 1023"
  }
until ( $ok )
$freespace *= 1GB
```

First, you prompt for a `[String]` and store it in `$entry`. Next, we *cast* the string value to an `[UInt64]` value using the `-as` operator. If the conversion fails, the `$freespace` variable will contain `$null`. The `do` loop will repeat until a numeric value is entered.

With the above code in your script, `$freespace` will be a numeric value after the `do` loop completes. The final line converts it to GB.

Answer (score 0):

your read host is a string not an int try the below

[int]$freespace = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter a value for Freespace'

Comment: This will work but only if you enter a numeric value. If you enter a non-numeric value, it will throw an error (which is probably not what you want). I would recommend casting using `-as` (see my answer).

Comment: Also note that the OP's desire is to recognize strings such as `'6GB'`  as the equivalent number (`6442450944`), which in _Windows PowerShell_ doesn't work with a cast / type constraint such as `[long] '6GB'`; it does work in _PowerShell (Core) 7+_, however.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the original question:

> Is there a way to get `Read-Host` to recognize PowerShell multipliers like KB, MB, GB, TB, and PB?

***Windows PowerShell* recognizes the *binary multiplier suffixes*** - `kb`, `mb`, `gb`, `tb`, `pb` - **in number *literals* only, *not* also when (implicitly) converting *from a string***, the latter being what the [`Read-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host) cmdlet invariably returns.

The only context where the string form *is* recognized is an *operator-based expression* in which a string operand is implicitly converted to a number, which enables a fairly simple and safe **workaround**.<sup>[1]</sup>

```
# 0 + forces the RHS string to be converted to a number, which
# in this particular context *does* work with binary multiplier suffixes 
PS> 0 + '1kb'
1024
```

This workaround also works in ***PowerShell (Core) 7+***, but there **you could simply use

`[long] '1kb'`**, because **such strings are now *consistently* supported during implicit to-number conversion**.

Applied to your code:

```
while ($true) {
  try { 
    $freeSpace = 0 + (Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter a value for Freespace')
    break # Valid input received; exit the loop.
  } catch { 
    Write-Warning 'Please enter a valid number.' # Prompt again.
  }
}

If ($freeSpace -lt 5GB) {
    "Free disk space is less than 5 GB"
} ElseIf ($freeSpace -lt 10GB) {
    "Free disk space is less than 10 GB"
} ElseIf ($freeSpace -lt 20GB) {
    "Free disk space is less than 20 GB"
} Else {
    "Free disk space is more than 20 GB"
}
```

---

<sup>[1] While using `Invoke-Expression` (`iex`) would technically work too, this cmdlet should generally be *avoided* and used only as a *last resort*, due to its inherent security risks. Superior alternatives are usually available. If there truly is no alternative, only ever use it on input you either provided yourself or fully trust - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375).</sup>